# How to compute angle using NumPy?

Tags: python, math, trigonometry

I have `x` and `y` pixel coordinates that I am using to compute angles. Initially I used the `math.atan2` approach but it gave me some issues as I was passing my data as an `array`. So now I am using the code below but the values that are being returned are not in the expected range of degrees. What am I doing wrong?

```
angle1 = np.arctan2(angle1_x, angle1_y)
angle2 = np.arctan2(angle2_x, angle2_y)
degrees = np.degrees(angle1 - angle2)
```

Comment: Hi MugB, welcome to SO! It's a little unclear to me right now what you're asking. Maybe an example of what you expect to happen and what's actually happening?

Comment: The first argument in `arctan2` is the sinus, so the `y` coordinate: try to inverse angle1_x and angle1_y

Comment: I'm guessing your range issues are due to the fact that you're taking the range produced by `arctan2`: `[-pi, pi]` and the subtraction operation will take that to the range `[-2*pi, 2*pi]` which doesn't really make much sense.

Comment: Here are 5 lines of code for demonstration which I am hesitant to put as an answer. Choose two points, one of which is origin: `angle1_x, angle1_y = 0, 0`, 
`angle2_x, angle2_y = -1, 1`, `angle1 = np.arctan2(angle1_y, angle1_x)`, `angle2 = np.arctan2(angle2_y, angle2_x)`, `degrees = np.degrees(angle2 - angle1)`. The answer is `135` degrees. Try this with your array now

Comment: i tried the inverse at seems to be giving bigger values. an example of the values i have is x1=267, y1=210, x2=274, y2=209 so the idea is to compute the degrees between these two angles.

Comment: Ok, you are confusing me now. You want to calculate the **degrees between these two angles**? What does that mean? You want the angle between two vectors connecting origin to the two points of which you know the coordinates, right?

Comment: sorry for the confusion, ok so I have x and y pixel coordinates for 3 points A, B and C, for angle1 - I am computing the angle from A to C and for angle2 I am computing from B to C. So I now want to calculate the degrees of these two angles.

Comment: Again confusing: Let me put it straight: If you have three points A, B, C, do you want to calculate the angle between the two lines: first line is A-C and second is  B-C. Am I right?

Comment: yes that's exactly what i meant. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you're trying to find the angle between two points `(x1, y1)` and `(x2, y2)`. For starters, as mentioned in the comments, you have the arguments the wrong way round. But even then your current solution doesn't really work.

`angle1` and `angle2` can be anywhere in the range `[-pi, pi]` so let's assume they are `pi` and `-pi` (which although they represent the same value, this is possible due to `0.0` and `-0.0` being different floats).

This gives a 'difference' of `2*pi` which is not quite what you want. If we switched them around it would be `-2*pi`. So our values are now in the range `[-2*pi, 2*pi]` which means that the same answer can be represented by multiple values. How do we fix this? By doing

```
angle_difference = (angle2 - angle1) % np.pi  # range == [0, 2*pi)
```

You'd need to do a bit more work to get into the range [-pi, pi].

```
angle_difference = angle_difference if angle_difference < np.pi else -2*np.pi + angle_difference
```

---

There is another way: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/227014/find-the-angle-between-two-vectors

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.linalg import norm

v1 = np.array([x1, y1])
v2 = np.array([x2, y2])

angle_difference = np.arccos((v1 @ v2) / (norm(v1) * norm(v2)))  # in range [0, pi]
```

However since this is symmetric it will give no indication as to the *direction* of the angle.

Comment: thanks I will try this solution but I am curious to know why the approach was straightforward when using math.atan2 that I just needed to pass the x and y coordinates and compute the degree compared to using this numpy approach?

Comment: @FHTMitchell: As I learned from the answer of OP to my comments above, origin is not the reference it seems. In your code, you compute angle between the vectors O-v1 and O-v2 where O is the origin. However the OP wants the angle between vectors A-C and B-C. So basically the angle A-C-B. The only modification your code will need is to define v1 as A-C and v2 as B-C.

Comment: yes, thanks for highlighting it @Bazingaa, as I tried this way and it's giving the expected degree values at the moment

Comment: Great. Try re-phrasing your question clearly in the future. It's more productive for you as well as for the people helping you.

Comment: sure I will. I realised that i was not using the correct terms so will make it clearer next time.